# Tracking down network usage

Tags: networking, router

I think I have a "rogue process" somewhere on my home network. My ISP tells me they're seeing an average of 4-5 GB of upload traffic during the day, which doesn't sound like normal usage (we don't use bittorrent).

I've installed an app (PeakHour 3) to pull usage statistics from my router's SNMP data, and sure enough, there are some huge upload/download numbers running across our network, even at times when we're not using our computers—though I do not know how to read the data coming out of the router. (I'm tracking the Ethernet and both wifi ports, but there are others that seem to have traffic.) I've looked at Activity Monitor's Network panel and don't see any obvious processes that are using huge amounts of bandwidth.

What's the best way for me to track down the process? Are there other apps I can use to break down the SNMP data by device?

The router is an Airport Extreme. There are three computers (all Macs) that connect to it regularly, plus two iPhones and an iPad. There is also an old Xbox 360 plugged directly in to the router, and a Chromecast that uses the wifi. There shouldn't be anything else on it, but I don't know how to get a log of all clients to the wifi network out of the Airport.

Comment: Change your password. Your request "Are there other apps I can use to break down the SNMP data by device?" is off topic.

Comment: Look into [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), which can allow you to see packets on your network and figure out what's what. You can create filters to ignore things you recognize, and you should be able to nail down where they're coming from.